# Wordpress: Menu item 'forum' disappear when it becomes Current-menu-item

Tags: wordpress, menu

After a number of updates in Wordpress, one of my menu items (Forum (Simple:Press) disappears when I choose this page in my menu.

Before the update it works all perfect, and at this moment all my other menu items are working good as well. So Only the Forum menu item gives this problem.

By inspecting of elements I saw that the word 'Forum' is missing.

Another menu item (Profiel) f.i. works fine. 
Profiel

Answer (score 0):

I wager that is is being hidden with CSS. Try to identify which style is applied to your menu item when it becomes active (probably the `.active` class is added), then look for it in your style.css or whatever.

There's a chance that there is the following attribute being applied to it:

```
.active {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: In the meantime the problem is solved. It was a bug in Simple:press